# Undefined variable in Controller

Tags: symfony

i have une dql query in repository :

```
public function TabloBordCmdPeriod($dat1,$dat2)
{$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->join('a.comElem','c')
    ->select("sum(c.total) as total")
    ->where("a.etat = 'Termine'")
    ->andwhere('a.dateCreation between :dat1 AND :dat2')
    ->setParameters(array('dat1'=>$dat1,'dat2'=>$dat2));
 $query = $qb->getQuery();
$resultats = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
 return $resultats;}
```

the query works well.

I use this query in search form (form without class),here is the code form :

```
class TBRechPeriodType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
$builder
->add('du','date',array('required'=>false,'widget' => 'single_text',  'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'attr' => array('class' => 'date input-medium')))
->add('au','date',array('required'=>false,'widget' => 'single_text',  'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'attr' => array('class' => 'date input-medium')))
;
}
public function getName(){
return 'Recherche_Periodique';}
}
```

and in the controller, the code is:

```
public function TBAction()
{
    $formTBrech=$this->createForm(new TBRechPeriodType());
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    if( $request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $formTBrech->bindRequest($request);
        if( $formTBrech->isValid() )
        {   $data = $formTBrech->getData();
             $period = $em->getRepository('ZXGescodBundle:Commande')->TabloBordCmdPeriod($data['du'],$data['au']);
        }
    }       
      $entities = $em->getRepository('ZXGescodBundle:Commande')->findall();
     return $this->render('ZXGescodBundle:Commande:TB.html.twig', array(
        'formTBrech' => $formTBrech->createView(),
        'period'      => $period,
        ));
}
```

when I load the template, I receive an error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: period in C:\wamp\www\elitetest\src\ZX\GescodBundle\Controller\CommandeController.php line...
```

how to solve it?
thank in advance

Comment: `'period' => isset($period) ? $period : null`

Answer (score -1):

when this is doesn't return any results

```
$em->getRepository('ZXGescodBundle:Commande')->TabloBordCmdPeriod($data['du'],$data['au']);
```

the variable $period is not assigned a value. 
So test it before assigning , or do as Leggendario suggested.

**EDIT**

Perhaps your form is not valid , so it skips the part where $period is assigned a the value.

```
if( $formTBrech->isValid() )
        {  error_log("form is valid"); $data = $formTBrech->getData();
            $period = $em->getRepository('ZXGescodBundle:Commande')->TabloBordCmdPeriod($data['du'],$data['au']);

        return $this->render('ZXGescodBundle:Commande:TB.html.twig', array(
           'formTBrech' => $formTBrech->createView(),
           'period'      => $period,
        ));
    } else {   error_log("form not valid");   ... }
```

Comment: in fact ,I do a search query dynamically through a form, there are two parameters date1 and date2,

I tested the $ variable period as stated leggendario, I still have the same error.